# Intersection of perpendicular bisectors

Tags: vectors

> Let $P$, $Q$ and $R$ be the midpoints of the sides $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ of $\Delta ABC$. Let $S$ be the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $AC$ and $BC$.

Now I have to prove that given $\langle \vec{s}-\vec{p},\vec{a}-\vec{c}\rangle=0$ and $\langle \vec{s}-\vec{q},\vec{a}-\vec{c}\rangle=0$, we have $\langle\vec{s}-\vec{r},\vec{b}-\vec{c}\rangle=0$. Can somebody give a hint? The algebraic manipulation is pretty heavy, and I don't make any progress..

Comment: It should be $\langle \vec{s}-\vec{p},\vec{b}-\vec{c}\rangle=0$.

Comment: @RobertZ was a typo, now fixed  :)

Comment: Write $\vec{r}$ in terms of $\vec{p}, \vec{q}.$ Then it is just a manipulation of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector approach. Let $P=(B+C)/2$, $Q=(A+C)/2$, $R=(A+B)/2$.
We know that
$$\langle S-P,B-C\rangle=0\implies  \langle S,B-C\rangle=\langle (B+C)/2,B-C\rangle,$$
$$\langle S-Q,A-C\rangle=0\implies  \langle S,A-C\rangle=\langle (A+C)/2,A-C\rangle.$$
By subtracting we get
$$\langle S,B-A\rangle=\langle(B+C)/2,B-C\rangle -\langle (A+C)/2,A-C\rangle\\
=\frac{1}{2}(\langle B,B\rangle-\langle A,A\rangle).$$
Now $\langle S-R,B-A\rangle=0$ iff
$$\langle S,B-A\rangle=\langle R,B-A\rangle=\langle(A+B)/2,B-A\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(\langle B,B\rangle-\langle A,A\rangle)$$
and we are done.

Geometric point of view. If $SP\perp CB$ then $|SC|=|SB|$.
If $SQ\perp AC$ then $|SC|=|SA|$. It follows that $|SB|=|SA|$, which imply that $S$ is on the bisector of $AB$.

Comment: I know this proof. I have to prove it using this dot product vector approach.\

Comment: @Cauchy the Dog Is it better now?

Comment: Thanks!! I don't understand this very step though: "$\langle S,B-A\rangle\langle R,B-A\rangle=\langle(A+B)/2,B-A\rangle$"

Comment: Sorry, $=$ was missing. I corrected my answer.